# How to trigger Jtable update after delete or insert in DB?

Tags: java, database, swing

I don't know how to refresh data in JTable after delete or after insert from other JDialog. I tried to initiate with calling `tabela();` after delete to refresh data in JTable but that don't work.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class LekariD extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTable table;
    private String lekar;
    private DefaultTableModel model1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            LekariD dialog = new LekariD();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Connection con = null;

    public void tabela () {

        Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<Object>();
        Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();

        try {
            String sql = "Select * from lekari";
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = md.getColumnCount();

            columnNames.addElement("Ime Lekara");
            columnNames.addElement("LBO");

            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                    row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
                }
                data.addElement( row );
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();  

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println( e );
        }

        model1 = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row, column);
                    if (o != null) {
                        return o.getClass();
                    }
                }
                return Object.class;
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public LekariD() {

        con = DatabaseConnector.dbConnector();

        tabela();

        setBounds(100, 100, 514, 654);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 126, 339, 478);
        contentPanel.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable(model1);
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
                int selectedRowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();

                lekar = model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString();
            }
        });
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Unos");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                NoviLekarD nl = new NoviLekarD();
                nl.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                nl.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(359, 126, 129, 44);
        contentPanel.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Brisanje");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
                try {
                    String query = "delete from lekari where ime_lekar = '"+lekar+"' ";
                    Statement stmt1 = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    stmt1.executeUpdate(query);
                    stmt1.close();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPanel, "Uspešno obrisan podatak", "Brisanje !", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    System.out.println( e2 );
                }
                //tabela(); - tried with this but don't work
            }
        });

        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(359, 212, 129, 44);
        contentPanel.add(btnNewButton_1);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Izlaz");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                dispose();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(359, 560, 129, 44);
        contentPanel.add(btnNewButton_2);

        JLabel lblSpisakLekara = new JLabel("Spisak lekara");
        lblSpisakLekara.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 18));
        lblSpisakLekara.setBounds(10, 42, 139, 38);
        contentPanel.add(lblSpisakLekara);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at what's happening:

1. When you call `tabela()` you query the database and create a `new DefaultTableModel` in `model1`.
2. During construction in `LekariD()` you create a new instance of `JTable` and provide it with `model1`.
3. On change you update the database and call `tabela()` again. This creates a `new DefaultTableModel` in `model1`. Your table still holds the previous `DefaultTableModel` and queries it whenever you require some data to be drawn.

So, what you have to do after `tabela()` is to provide your table with the new table model:

```
table.setModel(model1);
```

This let's your table know about the new data and makes it recalculate columns, redraw itself, etc.